# Tense disagreement of the irrealis forms "could ..." with "would have..."

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, tense-agreement

G. H. Hardy, "A Mathematician's Apology":

> Some hold that it is 'mental' and that in some sense we construct it, others that it is outside and independent of us. A man who **could** give a convincing account of mathematical reality **would have solved** very many of the most difficult problems of metaphysics. If he **could** include physical reality in his account, he **would have solved** them all.

In a first clause there is '*could*', in a second '*would have*'. Kind of a mixing, it should be either '*could have*' in a first, or just '*would*' in a second.

The only way I see it is that in **would [have solved]** the whole **have solved** stands for the verb (with a taste of the perfect aspect). But I have never read about it. It would mean that **have** belongs to either **would** or *the verb*: **would have [solved]**, **would [have solved]**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so much a matter of grammar as it is a matter of the hypothetical reality the grammar reflects.

In Hardy's view, a “convincing account of mathematical reality” cannot be given unless one **has already solved** certain difficult metaphysical problems, and an account of both mathematical and physical reality cannot be given unless one **has solved *all*** the difficult metaphysical problems.

Consequently, if I **could** provide you such an account, it **would** be convincing evidence that I **have solved** those problems.

Comment: 1. So both of them are mixed conditionals here, right? 2. But I have another interpretation of the original sentence (but in a different context): If he did be able to include physical reality in his account, then it was certain that he had solved them all.(past, real) Right? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng 1.I don't use the "nth-conditional" terminology, so you'll have to address that to somebody else. 2. Yes - except we don't use *DO* with *BE*: you have to say "if he *was* able".

Comment: Come to think of it, is the bold **have solved** a sham perfect or a true perfect in the quoted example?

Comment: @KinzleB It's a true perfect, by itself in a clause subordinate to the clause in which the *would* appears.